# Sending OTP via Authorize.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway, authorize.net

Is there any options for sending OTP while Credit/Debit card payment in authorize.net.

if there is no option how to achieve this

This is the code for getting response from the Authorized.Net

```
public static ANetApiResponse Run(CustomerDetail cd,decimal amount)
    {

        ApiOperationBase<ANetApiRequest, ANetApiResponse>.RunEnvironment = AuthorizeNet.Environment.SANDBOX;

        ApiOperationBase<ANetApiRequest, ANetApiResponse>.MerchantAuthentication = new merchantAuthenticationType()
        {
            name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorizeNetLogin"],
            ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.transactionKey,
            Item = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorizeNetTransactionKey"],
        };

        var creditCard = new creditCardType
        {
            cardNumber = Convert.ToString(cd.cardnumber),
            expirationDate = cd.expirationdate,
        };

        var paymentType = new paymentType { Item = creditCard };

        var transactionRequest = new transactionRequestType
        {
            transactionType = transactionTypeEnum.authOnlyTransaction.ToString(),    // authorize only
            amount = amount,
            payment = paymentType
        };

        var request = new createTransactionRequest { transactionRequest = transactionRequest };

        var controller = new createTransactionController(request);
        controller.Execute();

        var response = controller.GetApiResponse();
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: What is OTP????

Comment: one time password get from mobile. if we are transfer money from our account, security purpose bank site send one time password from register mobile.@JohnConde

Comment: You have asked a lot of question but have not accepted many answers. This site goes both ways. If you expect help you should reward those who help you by accepting their answer. Read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and start giving back to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorize.Net does not support One Time Password as Authorize.Net does not support money transfers.